# Ruby loops style/convention

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator, coding-style

I'm wondering how I would create the following psuedo-esque code's conventional equivalent in Ruby. I've read quite a bit regarding standard practices but I'm just curious what the generally accepted/cleanest approach to this specific loop structure might be. I haven't come across a direct example.

```
for(i = 0, j = 10; i < 10 && j > 0; i++, j--){
  //do something
}
```

Side note:
The intended purpose for this loop structure is to iterate through an array of arrays diagonally, the loop will contain a number of break-ing conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The intended purpose for this loop structure is to iterate through an array of arrays diagonally.

Given a square array of arrays:

```
array = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
```

You can traverse it diagonally (from top right to bottom left) via:

```
array.each.with_index(1) do |row, i|
  puts row[-i]
end
```

Output:

```
3
5
7
```

---

Or, if you prefer (or need) an index-based approach:

```
0.upto(2).zip(2.downto(0)).each do |i, j|
  p i: i, j: j, element: array[i][j]
end
```

Output:

```
{:i=>0, :j=>2, :element=>3}
{:i=>1, :j=>1, :element=>5}
{:i=>2, :j=>0, :element=>7}
```

You could also use `array.each_index.zip(array.each_index.reverse_each)`

Comment: This. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
(0..10).each do |j|
  i = 10 - j
  ...
end

# 0, 10 -> 10, 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact equivalent, but the result is the same:

```
10.times do |i|
  j = 10 - i
  # do something
end
```

Or

```
10.times.lazy.map{|i| [i, 10 - i]}.each do |i, j|
  # do something
end
```

Either way you have a cleaner solution than @gates' because they don't leak `i` and `j` out of the block.

Or you can try a more functional approach just for fun :)

```
(λ = ->(i, j) {
  # do something
  λ.(i + 1, j - 1) if i < 9 and j > 1
}).(0, 10)
```

But don't do this on large matrices, because Ruby doesn't optimize tail recursion thus may lead to stack overflow.

Comment: The last example is ruby?

Comment: Yes, it's pure Ruby.

Comment: is that an lambda? can you give some reference to this

Comment: Of course if you find difficult to type `λ`, you can change it to any valid identifier.

Comment: Syntax of lambda literal: `-> (params) {body}`, or `-> {body}` if the lambda takes no argument.

Comment: `λ.(params)` is a short version of `λ.call(params)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
i = 0
j = 10
loop do
  break if i > 9 || j < 1 
  # do something
  i = i + 1
  j = j - 1
end
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry- I should have included this as well. This is how I have it written currently but I guess I was wondering if there was something built in (like: each) similar to  `(0..10).each do |i| #dosomething end` that would appear more concise.